# str object is not callable for unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing

I have written a test case which shows the error

```
from unittest import *
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEquals(1,(2-1),"Sample Subraction Test")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:
Str object is not callable

Instead of 
"from unittest import *" I have given 
"import unittest"

it worked

but still i couldn't get point it accurately 
what might be the reason for this?

Comment: For me, your script raises the error `NameError: name 'unittest' is not defined`, as expected.  If you import the symbols from `unittest` into the main module, there is no name `unittest`.

Comment: As @Sven pointed out, your script gives a `NameError` on the line `class MyTest(unittest.TestCase)` because the `from unittest import *` does not result in the name `unittest` being bound to anything. Changing it to just `import unittest` resolves this.  I don't understand what you mean by "but still i couldn't get point it accurately" -- please rephrase.

Comment: @sven and @marti NameError is my mistake; There was a mistaken actually instead that(unittest.TestCase) if you give only "TestCase" .you will get "str object is not callble" ; that is my dubious place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`from ... import *` is dangerous practice, and should only be used when the module/package has been designed and advertised that way, and you have a good reason to do so.

It turns out that unittest has not been designed that way, and when that method is used two other 'test cases' are found, but since they aren't really test cases, they create problems.

The correct way to do what you want is:

```
import unittest
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_subtraction(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, (2-1), "Sample Subraction Test")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In researching this issue I discovered that the `__all__` variable can and should be used to define the public API -- its presence does not indicate that `from ... import *` is supported.

Comment: Same issue if you use "from requests import get", apparently

Answer (score -1):

I got it working like this. 
Override runTest() method, create instance, run your test_add()

```
from unittest import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        pass

    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEquals(1,(2-2),"Sample Subraction Test")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = MyTest()
    test.test_add()
```

Comment: Even you will get "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
"

Comment: I got "AssertionError: Sample Subraction Test" (PythonWin 2.6.6)

Comment: there is the problem with "from unittest import *" How will be assertion error? i think this doesn't have any assertion error

Comment: I used python 2.6.5 Is there any versioning issue?